# Opening one page and refreshing the current page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my application the user will fill certain page and after that, he will safe the data to the database. After saving the data to the database, he will need to print the data and refresh the page to accept new input. I have done the following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('PrintHelperDocument.aspx','PrintMe','height=500px,width=1000px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
Response.Redirect("BondData.aspx");
```

If I did this, the print page is not opened and only the current page get refreshed. how can I open the new page and at the same time refresh the current one?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your sample does not render the client script that is responsible for opening the print page, because the response redirect tells the browser to show the other page directly.

In order to solve this, you can change the window location in Javascript instead of the redirect. To do so, you add another Startup-script, e.g. like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
  "onclick", 
  "<script language=javascript>window.open('PrintHelperDocument.aspx','PrintMe','height=500px,width=1000px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
  "redirect", 
  "<script language=\"JavaScript\">window.location = 'BondData.aspx';></script>");
```